# Not getting value in async pipe when selector pushes value after template initialisation

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have an Angular component that fetches data from a service and displays it by using the async pipe.
The service gets the data form the store via an ngrx selector.

The observable in the service is not emitting any value.

// TestComponent

```
export class TestComponent {

    test$ = this.testService.test$;
    constructor() {

        this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
            const id = paramMap.get('id');
            this.testService.getDetails(id);
        });
    }
}
```

// TestComponent template

```
<p>{{test$ | async}}</p>
```

// TestService

```
export class TestService {

    test$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    }

    getDetails(id) {
        this.test$ = this.store.select(TestSelectors.getDetailsById(id)).pipe(
            map(details => details.test)
        );
    }
}
```

If instead of assigning test$ to the transformed selector value after getting the url param I do it when the variable is declared in the service, the value is displayed correctly in the template.
So I know it has something to do with timing and when the subscription in the template takes place in relation to when the selector emits a value, but I can't figure out what problem is and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats about this:

```
constructor() {

    test$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      exhaustMap(paramMap => this.testService.getDetails(paramMap.get('id')))
    )
}
```

and in your service:

```
getDetails(id) {
  return this.store.select(TestSelectors.getDetailsById(id)).pipe(
      map(details => details.test)
  );
}
```

Comment: using exhaustMap would mean that any routing occuring during a call to getDetails would be ignored

Comment: yes - and? Store will always deliver you values synchronously

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Could you explain the use of exhaustmap? I have tried reading the definition but I find it hard to understand...Does it mean if the params change I won't call get details until getDetails has returned a value?

Comment: Yes exactly - as Davy says you also could use mergeMap - in this case there would no difference because store selects are immediately. In case you would call an API, mergeMap would probably the better solution. Here is a nice Post about these operators: https://medium.com/@shairez/a-super-ninja-trick-to-learn-rxjss-switchmap-mergemap-concatmap-and-exhaustmap-forever-88e178a75f1b

Answer (score 1):

When the component is created, the value of this.testService.test$ is assigned to test$.

```
test$ = this.testService.test$;
```

But, testService.test$ is only created when getDetails is called in your constructor. Your variable delaration happens before your constructor.

My guess is that the test$ variable is null or undefined, and that async is simply silent about it instead of throwing an exception.

This would be a possible solution:

```
export class TestComponent {

    public test$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

        this.test$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
            map(paramMap => paramMap.get('id')),
            mergeMap(id => this.testService.getDetails(id))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the reason why it doesn't work and the solution works. Does the use of mergeMap mean that if the url params change, I will call getDetails with the new params every time?

Comment: Yes. An observable is a stream of event, so every time we receive a new set of parameters, the map operator will pick out the id from the paramMap, and the mergeMap will feed that id into your service call and return the result. While the map operator is for simply returning values, mergeMap (or one of its variants) will first resolve the observable that is returned by your service call,and return its value.

Comment: If you can find the time, do read this article:
https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/
I have only started learning rxjs myself not too long ago, and gaining a clear understanding of these "higher order" mapping operators was one of the important milestones ;)

Comment: by the way (a little smart-ass), the example code Davy show, only work if you also change the service call to return an Observable like in my example

Comment: True! Forgot to mention that :)